# Switching of image in an ImageSwitcher is not working properly

Tags: android, multithreading, imageswitcher

I m storing `image` from server in an `Bitmap arrayList`, then using a `thread` which waits 3 second, switching the image.Suppose the size of `arraylist` is 3.then after switching 3 image one after another, its waiting another 3sec but now there is no image. and again its circulating from 0. 
I m not getting why this extra 3sec its waiting.

***Code for the tread is..***

```
ImageSwitcher dailywear;
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapDailywear = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
dailyWear.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmapDailyWear.get(0)));

final Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        int i = 1;

        public void run() {


            dailyWear.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmapDailyWear.get(i)));
            i++;
            if (i == bitmapDailyWear.size())
                i = 0;

            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);

        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 3000);
```

Comment: please explain your question .... where r you getting this extra 3 sec

Comment: @kumarkundan  - i am loading all image in an bitmap arraylist, when i m putting the thread, then image is switching one after another till the size of the arraylist.
after loading the image of last index of the arraylist , then its waiting for 3 sec and no image are there at that time (this is the extra 3sec)
after this 3 sec is passing its again starts switching , from the array lindex 0.